# Algebraic Solution to an equation

Tags: logarithms

What is the algebraic solution to this equation $x^2+2^x-2=0$
I know the numeric solution using graphing which is $\{-1.258,0.653\}$
NB. It's graph looks like parabola

Also what is the algebraic solution to this equation $x^2-2^x=0$
I know the numeric solution using graphing which is $\{-0.767,2,4\}$
NB. It's graph looks like Cubic Equation

Comment: Such equations require either numerical methods or the lambert-w-function. There is no algebraic solution-method to such equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation may be solved using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$x^2=2^x\\-x=2^{x/2}\\ [-x\ln(2)/2]e^{[-x\ln(2)/2]}=\ln(2)/2\\-x\ln(2)/2=W(\ln(2)/2)\\x=-\frac{W(\ln(2)/2)}{\ln(2)/2}\approx-0.767$$

Likewise, the positive solutions come down to $x=2$ and $x=4$.

The first equation cannot be solved in the same manner and requires a numerical method:

$$x^2+2^x-2=0\\x=\sqrt{2-2^x}$$

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-2^{x_n}}$$

Set $x_0=0.5$, then we have

$x_1=0.76537$

$x_2=0.54790$

$x_3=0.73351$

$\vdots$

$x_{35}=0.65374$

The negative solution may be found using

$$x_{n+1}=-\sqrt{2-2^{x_n}}$$

with $x_0=-1$, we get

$x_1=-1.22474$

$x_2=-1.25384$

$x_3=-1.25725$